# Count of value occurrence in two columns stimulatenously, python

Tags: python, pandas

Good day,

I have a question, a very basic question. Let's say I have a dataset with user ratings of a movie in rows and movies in columns. I need to find the movies that occur with the movie2. For example, for the movie1, the percentage of the movie2 raters who also rated the movie1 is 0.5 - the number of people who saw both, the movie1 and movie2 is 1 divided by the total number of people seeing and rating the movie2.

Dataset:

```
import numpy as np
df = np.array([['','Movie1','Movie2','Movie3'],
                ['User1',1,0,2],
                ['User2',2,4,4],
                ['User3',4,0,4],
                ['User4',0,2,4]])
print(pd.DataFrame(data=df[1:,1:],
                  index=df[1:,0],
                  columns=df[0,1:]))
```

The line below finds the number of users who rated a movie. My question is how to add one more condition which also checks whether a corresponding cell in the col movie2 is not 0 - 0 indicates that a person has not seen the movie, it was marked as the missing value in the original dataset:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x!=0]).count(axis=0)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand.. Can you elaborate? `For example, for the movie1, the percentage of the movie2 raters who also rated the movie1 is 0.5`. HOW? `the number of people who saw both, the movie1 and movie2 is 1 divided by the total number of people seeing and rating the movie2.`? What logic is this?

Comment: See the response below.

Answer (score 0):

Two things in your code

1st you create the data frame by `np.array` , base on the official document, `np.array`, only accept one data type per time , so your `numeric` is automatically transform to `string`

```
df.applymap(type)
Out[787]: 
              Movie1         Movie2         Movie3
User1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
User2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
User3  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
User4  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

2nd the solution

```
maskdf=df.ne('0')

maskdf.Movie1[maskdf.Movie2].mean()
Out[795]: 0.5
```

---

Change your `apply` code

```
df.ne('0').sum(axis=1)
Out[786]: 
User1    2
User2    3
User3    2
User4    2
dtype: int64


df.ne('0').sum()
Out[788]: 
Movie1    3
Movie2    2
Movie3    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi Wen and Abhishek, thank you for the response. What I need is to count how many users reviewed (rating !=0), for example, the movie1 AND the movie2 and divide by the # of users who reviewed the movie2. The same is for movie3 i.e. how many users reviewed the movie3 AND the movie2 and divide by the # of users who reviewed the movie2. So, I go a col by col (to remind you, movies are in cols) checking how many users review the corresponding movie AND movie2. It is normal logic, @Abhishek )